# NGINX + FLASK + UWSGI 502 upstream prematurely close connection

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

При загрузке и длительной обработке данных постоянно появляется 502. В uwsgi logs ошибок нет. Очень нужна помощь в решении проблемы.

```
app.ini
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5

socket = app.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

daemonize = /var/log/wsgi/app.log
touch-reload = /var/www/wa.binotel/app.py
die-on-term = true
enable-threads = false

harakiri = 3000
socket-timeout = 3000
limit-post = 5120000
post-buffering = 5120000

nginx
 server {
listen 80;
server_name wa.binotel.space www.wa.binotel.space;

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/wa.binotel/app.sock;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 3000s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 3000s;
}

client_max_body_size 1000M;

sendfile                       on;
keepalive_timeout               0;
send_timeout                3000s;
proxy_connect_timeout       3000s;
proxy_send_timeout          3000s;
proxy_read_timeout          3000s;
fastcgi_send_timeout        3000s;
fastcgi_read_timeout        3000s;
uwsgi_read_timeout          3000s;
uwsgi_send_timeout          3000s;
```

}